# Find Specific String in google sheet and range Cell notation using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets

I'm looking for a solution to search for specific string in a range lets say A:A in google sheet from python.String is found then I want to extract its cell Notation like A1, A2, A3 or any other where staring found. Please guide

I was able to do same in AppScript however I'm new on python so looking for help if method is already available for same.

Comment: You can use the gspread library along with Google Sheets API to interact with Google Sheets from Python.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `gspread` library. You'll need to set up credentials for the Google Sheets API and then use the following code snippet to search for the string and get the cell notation:

```py
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# Set up the credentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('path_to_your_credentials.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Open the spreadsheet and the worksheet
spreadsheet = client.open('your_spreadsheet_name')
worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet('your_worksheet_name')

# Search the string in column A
search_string = 'your_search_string'
cell = worksheet.find(search_string, in_column=1)  # 1 is the index of column A
if cell:
    cell_notation = gspread.utils.rowcol_to_a1(cell.row, cell.col)
    print(f'String found at {cell_notation}')
else:
    print('String not found')
```

Remember to replace `'path_to_your_credentials.json'`, `'your_spreadsheet_name'`, `'your_worksheet_name'`, and `'your_search_string'` with your actual credentials filepath, spreadsheet name, worksheet name, and the string you are searching for.